# Accute accent MySQL - PHP - UTF-8

Tags: php, sql, encoding

- I have set the meta charset to UTF-8

  ```
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  ```
- I have set my Notepad++ encoding to UTF-8 without bom
- I have set my MySql's database collation to ut8_general_ci
- I have set the collation for each field to utf8_general_ci

I have done all that and I still can't see accute accents (é). Instead I see �...
Hopefuly you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you done a `SET NAMES utf8` or, better, a client equivalent (eg mysql(i)_set_charset)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure to run `SET NAMES utf8` on the database

Example (with the use of PDO):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb', 'root', '', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Comment: It tells the database in what charset it should be returning your data (I guess in your cas utf-8 isn't it's default)

Comment: But what is the collation for then?

Comment: It's for storing your data. If your - let's say - varchar field had its collation set to ASCII, it wouldn't be able to store non-ASCII characters (like é, č or ř).

Answer (score 0):

Set also the charset of the database connection. Setting this parameter will tell your database object to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings, even if they are stored otherwise in the database. Of course storing the data in the same format UTF-8 will make the delivering faster.

```
// tells the mysqli connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$db->set_charset('utf8');

// tells the pdo connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPassword);

// tells the mysql connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db);
```

[more…](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8)